# How to reduce the length of a hexadecimal string in Android?

Tags: android, hex

In my application I encrypted and decrypted a string using the AES algorithm. But the encrypted string is coming as a hexadecimal string and the length of it goes on increasing as we increase the length of the string that needs to be encrypted. Could you please tell me if there is any such way in which I can reduce the length of the encrypted string?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In hex you usually go with fixed size like two chars per byte (00-FF) or prefixed format (like 0x0 - 0xFF). So basically there's no much room for improvement, beside doing [data compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression) - either on source data or output hex string.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Otherwise, could you please let me know if there is any better way to encrypt and decrypt so that I get an encrypted string whose length is as less as possible?